# Running android studio app on physical device "ERROR IN NETWORK CONNECTION"

Tags: java, android, mobile

Whenever I try to login, register, change password or reset password the app just says "Error In Network Connection".

I am using strong internet connection, could you please advise as I have tried to on WI-FI and 4G, however it still says the same error. I am using WAMP server to connect to phpMyAdmin database. Please could you help and advise.

Login. Java File

```
public class Login extends Activity {

    Button BtnLogin;
    Button Btnregister;
    Button passreset;
    EditText inputEmail;
    EditText inputPassword;
    private TextView loginErrorMsg;
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
    private static String KEY_USERNAME = "uname";
    private static String KEY_FIRSTNAME = "fname";
    private static String KEY_LASTNAME = "lname";
    private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pword);
        Btnregister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registerbtn);
       BtnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginbtn);
        passreset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.passres);

        loginErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loginErrorMsg);

        passreset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), PasswordReset.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                finish();
            }});


        Btnregister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Register.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                finish();
            }});

/**
 * Login button click event
 * A Toast is set to alert when the Email and Password field is empty
 **/
        BtnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {

                if ((!inputEmail.getText().toString().equals("")) && (!inputPassword.getText().toString().equals(""))) {
                    NetAsync(view);
                } else if ((!inputEmail.getText().toString().equals(""))) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Password field empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if ((!inputPassword.getText().toString().equals(""))) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Email field empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Email and Password field are empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    /**
     * Async Task to check whether internet connection is working.
     **/

    private class NetCheck extends AsyncTask<String,String,Boolean>
    {
        private ProgressDialog nDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
            nDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
            nDialog.setTitle("Checking Network");
            nDialog.setMessage("Loading..");
            nDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            nDialog.setCancelable(true);
            nDialog.show();
        }
        /**
         * Gets current device state and checks for working internet connection by trying Google.
         **/
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... args){



            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
                    HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    urlc.setConnectTimeout(3000);
                    urlc.connect();
                    if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                        return true;
                    }
                } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return false;

        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean th){

            if(th == true){
                nDialog.dismiss();
                new ProcessLogin().execute();
            }
            else{
                nDialog.dismiss();
                loginErrorMsg.setText("Error in Network Connection");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Async Task to get and send data to My Sql database through JSON respone.
     **/
    private class ProcessLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {


        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        String email,password;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
            inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pword);
            email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
            pDialog.setTitle("Contacting Servers");
            pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
            JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(email, password);
            return json;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
            try {
                if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {

                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);

                    if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                        pDialog.setMessage("Loading User Space");
                        pDialog.setTitle("Getting Data");
                        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                        JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");
                        /**
                         * Clear all previous data in SQlite database.
                         **/
                        UserFunctions logout = new UserFunctions();
                        logout.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                        db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_FIRSTNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_LASTNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL),json_user.getString(KEY_USERNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_UID),json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));
                        /**
                         *If JSON array details are stored in SQlite it launches the User Panel.
                         **/
                        Intent upanel = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main.class);
                        upanel.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        startActivity(upanel);
                        /**
                         * Close Login Screen
                         **/
                        finish();
                    }else{

                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        loginErrorMsg.setText("Incorrect username/password");
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    public void NetAsync(View view){
        new NetCheck().execute();
    }
}
```

Register.java File

```
public class Register extends Activity {


    /**
     *  JSON Response node names.
     **/


    private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
    private static String KEY_FIRSTNAME = "fname";
    private static String KEY_LASTNAME = "lname";
    private static String KEY_USERNAME = "uname";
    private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";
    private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";

    /**
     * Defining layout items.
     **/

    EditText inputFirstName;
    EditText inputLastName;
    EditText inputUsername;
    EditText inputEmail;
    EditText inputPassword;
    Button btnRegister;
    TextView registerErrorMsg;


    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);

        /**
         * Defining all layout items
         **/
        inputFirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fname);
        inputLastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lname);
        inputUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uname);
        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pword);
        btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);
        registerErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.register_error);



/**
 * Button which Switches back to the login screen on clicked
 **/

        Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bktologin);
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Login.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                finish();
            }

        });

        /**
         * Register Button click event.
         * A Toast is set to alert when the fields are empty.
         * Another toast is set to alert Username must be 5 characters.
         **/

        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (  ( !inputUsername.getText().toString().equals("")) && ( !inputPassword.getText().toString().equals("")) && ( !inputFirstName.getText().toString().equals("")) && ( !inputLastName.getText().toString().equals("")) && ( !inputEmail.getText().toString().equals("")) )
                {
                    if ( inputUsername.getText().toString().length() > 4 ){
                        NetAsync(view);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Username should be minimum 5 characters", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "One or more fields are empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    /**
     * Async Task to check whether internet connection is working
     **/

    private class NetCheck extends AsyncTask<String,String,Boolean>
    {
        private ProgressDialog nDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
            nDialog = new ProgressDialog(Register.this);
            nDialog.setMessage("Loading..");
            nDialog.setTitle("Checking Network");
            nDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            nDialog.setCancelable(true);
            nDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... args){


/**
 * Gets current device state and checks for working internet connection by trying Google.
 **/
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
                    HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    urlc.setConnectTimeout(3000);
                    urlc.connect();
                    if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                        return true;
                    }
                } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return false;

        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean th){

            if(th == true){
                nDialog.dismiss();
                new ProcessRegister().execute();
            }
            else{
                nDialog.dismiss();
                registerErrorMsg.setText("Error in Network Connection");
            }
        }
    }





    private class ProcessRegister extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

        /**
         * Defining Process dialog
         **/
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        String email,password,fname,lname,uname;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            inputUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uname);
            inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pword);
            fname = inputFirstName.getText().toString();
            lname = inputLastName.getText().toString();
            email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            uname= inputUsername.getText().toString();
            password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Register.this);
            pDialog.setTitle("Contacting Servers");
            pDialog.setMessage("Registering ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {


            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
            JSONObject json = userFunction.registerUser(fname, lname, email, uname, password);

            return json;


        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
            /**
             * Checks for success message.
             **/
            try {
                if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                    registerErrorMsg.setText("");
                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);

                    String red = json.getString(KEY_ERROR);

                    if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                        pDialog.setTitle("Getting Data");
                        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Info");

                        registerErrorMsg.setText("Successfully Registered");


                        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                        JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                        /**
                         * Removes all the previous data in the SQlite database
                         **/

                        UserFunctions logout = new UserFunctions();
                        logout.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                        db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_FIRSTNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_LASTNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL),json_user.getString(KEY_USERNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_UID),json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));
                        /**
                         * Stores registered data in SQlite Database
                         * Launch Registered screen
                         **/

                        Intent registered = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Registered.class);

                        /**
                         * Close all views before launching Registered screen
                         **/
                        registered.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        startActivity(registered);


                        finish();
                    }

                    else if (Integer.parseInt(red) ==2){
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        registerErrorMsg.setText("User already exists");
                    }
                    else if (Integer.parseInt(red) ==3){
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        registerErrorMsg.setText("Invalid Email id");
                    }

                }


                else{
                    pDialog.dismiss();

                    registerErrorMsg.setText("Error occured in registration");
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();


            }
        }}
    public void NetAsync(View view){
        new NetCheck().execute();
    }}
```

Manifest.java File

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.brad.visor" >

    <application
        android:icon="@mipmap/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Login">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Register">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Registered">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Main">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".PasswordReset">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ChangePassword">
        </activity>
    </application>

    <!-- Allow to connect with internet and to know the current network state-->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />


</manifest>
```

I think the problem is somewhere in the doInBackground method.

Comment: Try adding Internet Access Permission in your manifest.

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: I already have this in my manifest file, could it be with the device I have used all samsung device and still get the same error message.

Comment: Could you add logging statements to your doInBackground Method. try Log.i("code",urlc.getResponseCode() );

Comment: could you please rewrite the code for me as I don't understand what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

```
     NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
                    try {
                        URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
                        HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        urlc.setConnectTimeout(3000);
                        urlc.connect();
Log.i("code",urlc.getResponseCode() );
                        if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Comment: I am just going to run my device

Comment: Do you get a exception? Can you post the exception?

Comment: no I dont I only get a red line, however i have imported the log method into my class. I just get a red line near getResponseCode();

Comment: Log.i("code", Integer.toString(urlc.getResponseCode() )); try this. Sorry for making you wait because of my wrong code

Comment: I am now debugging my app

Comment: when debugging it says variable information not available.

Comment: I have the below error when debugging the whole application. Unable to open debugger port (localhost:8600): java.io.IOException "handshake failed - connection prematurally closed

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.